# How to populate dropdown list based on selection of another dropdown (Wordpress Form Maker)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to populate a second dropdown list based on selection from a first dropdown list using WordPress plugin Form Maker by WebDorado.
I have two tables on MySQL db "Company" and "Branches" which is linked to the first one by the foreign key company_id.
I have a first dropdown menù populated from "company" table and i would like that the second dropdown menù ("branches") shall be filled according to the selection on the first one (by usign the foreign key).
How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any code to provide?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider reviewing this link and editing your post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask